# How to use JModel in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm developing a component for Joomla 3, but I don't understand how to use the datamodel in joomla 3. Am I supposed to use the Legacy-classes? Will these not be deprecated after a while?

I see most of the joomla components are using the class JModelList, which extends JModelLegacy. To load such a class I can use

```
JModelLegacy::getInstance('classname');
```

but is there a way to do this without using legacy-classes? I would think that the word legacy implies that the code hase been replace for something newer/better/hotter? Please enlighten me if anyone knows better ...

PS: I also asked this question on the Joomla - forum, but got no replies (http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=837707)

regards Jonas

Comment: You can use either, it's up to you. I love the new classes but there are not all of the child classes that there are in the legacy classes, though hopefully we will have them soon. I have some that I wrote in my repo. https://github.com/elinw/joomla-cms/tree/checkin-cache-plugins-tags  the named components are examples (along with com_config) and the child classes are in the cms library. YMMV.  Also there are a couple of tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use JModelList and JModelForm because this way PHP error logging will notify during code execution if your class has failed to meet some of its "contractual" class obligations from any of the parent/super classes.

The answer depends on yourself, and there is really no "wrong" answer here.  Pick the method which makes the most sense to you and go with it.

** EDIT **

You can always load and instantiate a model class like so, using User's registration model as example.

```
JLoader::register('UsersModelRegistration', JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_users/models/registration.php');
$model = new UsersModelRegistration();
```

Comment: He's asking which class his class should extend though.

Comment: Hi, thanks both of you. I'm thinking that the legacy-classes will be deprecated after a while, that's why I thought I shouldn't use them, but the API that is not legacy seems very incomplete. 

Anyway, thanks for the clarification on loading models not on the path. I still dont feel comfortable working with the joomla API... 
regards Jonas

Comment: @jonasfh No problem, just keep in mind I once stared at Joomla 1.5 with the same bewilderment as you did.  There's no magic recipe outside of to keep tinkering.  There is a fantastic book I recommend if you would like an amazing walk through on all Joomla programming called Joomla Programming.  It is 2.5 focus, but still very relevant for anyone interested in a deeper, guided dive into Joomla programming.